# CssRewriteUrlTransform missing in System.Web.Optimization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, system.web.optimization

I'm trying to use CssRewriteUrlTransform but am having a problem referencing it.
I updated to the latest  Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization using package manager:

> update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization -reinstall

And can now see System.Web.Optimization v4.0.30319 referenced in my project.
However I'm still getting

> Error 19  The type or namespace name 'CssRewriteUrlTransform' could not
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Is there something else I'm missing?

(I've got using System.Web.Optimization;)
VS Cannot 'resolve' the issue.

Comment: Are you sure there is an added reference to System.Web.Optimization in the project that contains the code?

Comment: Btw, I don't see that class in the v4.0.30319 of that assembly.

Comment: I made a mistake in this question.  Late Friday Evening mode! It was version 1.1.0.0 of the assembly (Runtime version 4.0.30319)
I never really got to the bottom of what fixed this, but I went into Nuget Package manager and installed it that way and it started working.

Comment: thanks,  i had the same issue, and installed **version 1.1.3**, form [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.web.optimization/)